# React Native - 'useNativeDriver' was not specified in modal

Tags: react-native

I'm building a modal which displays a zoomable image using the library [react-native-image-viewer](https://github.com/ascoders/react-native-image-viewer). This is my custom component:

```
       <Modal
            animationType="slide"
            visible={isVisible}
            transparent={true}
        >
            <ImageViewer imageUrls={images} />
        </Modal>
```

The thing is when I click on the image, the modal shows up and it displays the zoomable image but with this warning message:

> Animated: `useNativeDriver` was not specified. This is a required option and must be explicitly set to `true` or `false`

I've been searching a lot and the solutions found where to include something like this:

```
animatedValue = new Animated.Value(-300);

componentDidMount() {
    Animated.timing(this.animatedValue,
        {
            toValue: 0,
            duration: 3000,
            useAnimatedDriver: true,
        }).start();
}
```

and including *ImageViewer* inside an Animated.View component, but I've tried it and I still have the same warning. Any solution?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find a solution please ? I have the same problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is because RN team made `useNativeDriver` as a required property https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/5876052615f4858ed5fc32fa3da9b64695974238 and `react-native-image-viewer` maintainer haven't updated its implementation.